# Does a UNIQUE constraint implicity contain the primary key?

Tags: mysql

I'm aware that INNODB includes an implicit primary key in an index such as:

```
INDEX (non_primary_column)
```

Does it apply to the UNIQUE constraint too?

```
UNIQUE (other_primary_column) -- equivalent to INDEX (other_primary_column, pkey)?
```

… and FOREIGN constraint too?

```
FOREIGN KEY (some_other_column) -- equivalent to INDEX (some_other_column, pkey)?
```

Comment: Any index contains **clustered** (it may be NOT primary) index expression hiddenly. Constraint is NOT an index (it is a rule), and so it cannot contain any expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes in that the PK column(s) are tacked onto each `UNIQUE` index and the `INDEX` implicitly generated by each `FOREIGN KEY`.

No in that the PK column(s) are not part of the uniqueness constraint implied by `UNIQUE`.

For example:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE(x)
```

is like

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(x,id) and a uniqueness constraint on only `(x)`.
```

`FOREIGN KEY(y)` will generate `INDEX(y)` unless it finds an existing index starting with `y`.